# How to use URI + STRING (user input)

Tags: java, android

I'm learning to code, this is my first attempt (day 1) and I'm trying to do something simple but I can't get it to work.

I have the main activity where the user enter data on text view and a button that send that data to a string and start another activity.

on the other activity I have an URI, what I want it to do is to take a partial link and add the string (user input) at the end of it and launch it.

"www.link.com/ + what the user entered (that should be on the string)"

Here is mi main activity java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String link;

    EditText  linkInput;

    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        linkInput= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumberImput);

        button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                link= linkinput.getText().toString();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ToBrowseract.class));
            }

        });



    }
}
```

and here is my second activity java:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import static android.net.Uri.parse;

public class ToBrowseract extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    Uri uri;

    {
        uri = parse("https://url.net/" + getString("link"));
    }

    private String getString(String link) {
        return link;
    }
}
```

The xml works fine. most of this I got it reading some tutorials but there is some stuff that android studio added automatically or when checking the errors.
I don't know where it stops working, how can I check if the user imput goes to the string? and I'm kinda sure that URI doesn't work like I wrote it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass your link to the next `Activity`, you want to use a `Bundle`. This will allow you to pass data and read it from the `Intent`.

In your `onClick`, create a `Bundle` and put your link in as a `String`. It uses a key/value pair, so we're saying `"link"` is our link.

And then when you call `startActivity`, you can pass that `Bundle`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String link = linkinput.getText().toString();

    // Storing the link into the bundle to pass to the next Activity.
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("link", link);

    // Creating an Intent for which Activity to launch.
    Intent intent = new Intent((MainActivity.this, ToBrowseract.class);

    // Starting the new Activity with the Bundle with the link.
    startActivity(intent, bundle);
}
```

Now, in your `ToBrowseract` `Activity`, you want to read from the `Intent`. You can get the `Intent`, and then you can just fetch any "extras", which we ask for our `"link"`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Fetching the link from the Intent.
    String link = getIntent().getStringExtra("link");

    // .. display the link
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity pass the user input "link" as an extra in the intent. To do that, change your startActivity() code as below:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ToBrowseract.class).putExtra("myUri", link));
```

In your second activity get the link as below:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String link = bundle.getString("link");
    Uri uri = parse("https://url.net/" + link);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different activities, and you are saving your string into link variable on the first activity without passing this data into your second activity.
In android you can pass data between 2 different activities by adding your data into your intent in this way:

**In your first activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("yourData", link);
startActivity(intent);
```

**In your second activiy retrive that data :**

```
String link = getIntent().getStringExtra("yourData");
uri = parse("https://url.net/" + link);
```